# How to wait for event triggered page reloads with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying safely handle the behavior of a page which uses an in-browser event on a `select` element to trigger a page reload (POST). The URL is the same but the page reloads with the same HTML and the only difference is the sort order of content in a table. I tried several methods but somehow none are reliable, how can I achieve something like this:

```
    try {
        await page.select('select[name=sort]', 'size'); 
        await page.waitForNextPageReload();
        await page.waitForSelector('select[name=sort]');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error sorting page.');
    }
```

Basically, `waitForNextPageReload` doesn't exist but I'm looking for something which would provide similar results. I tried to add 'delays' but I'm looking for something more reliable to manage errors correctly.

Comment: Can you provide the URL to test the code?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not available publicly. I can see if I can possibly write a demo of its behavior today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a race condition between selecting and navigation promises (see examples [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options) or [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions)). Can you try this approach?

```js
await Promise.all([
  page.select('select[name=sort]', 'size'),
  page.waitForNavigation(),
]);

await page.waitForSelector('select[name=sort]');
```

Comment: Looks like this did the trick! I guess I will know better now on how to deal with those race conditions!

Answer (score 2):

Try [`page.waitForNavigation`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.13.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions).

Quoting from puppeteer docs:

> This resolves when the page navigates to a new URL or reloads. It is useful for when you run code which will indirectly cause the page to navigate.

It seems good for your use case where you are indirectly reloading the page

Comment: thanks but I have tried that and I'm getting a timeout for some reasons. I'm suspecting that since the navigation is triggered by a browser event, Puppeteer does not behave well with it?

Comment: Is it possible to try non headless mode and ensure that the page is reloading?

Comment: Yes, I tried that already and it is reloading. Maybe here again the problem is that the URL remains the same, so is most of the HTML content (so I can't really look for a new element either).

Comment: Oh and it's also reloading sending a POST method - not sure if this impacts the `waitForNavigation` behavior.